# changing rows order every other one

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a series of ".row" bootstrap elements which are consecutive like below:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">3</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">5</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">6</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">7</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">8</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="elem">9</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to change the row order every other one dynamically with CSS. Can someone help me?

The desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: ???  *row order every other one* , 2 rows , you want to reverse order?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to reverse the orders Every other row dynamically. suppose that i may have 'n' rows. thanks

Comment: Question is not clear. Post any jpeg representation of required output.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Use custom css and use row:nth(odd) and add your styles for reverse order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="elem">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this but my results are generated dynamically so i need a solution in CSS or sth else that could do that dynamically.

Comment: A pure CSS way would be : `.row:nth-child(even){ flex-direction: row-reverse; }` which is what the helper class `flex-row-reverse` is likely doing, as suggested by Tom.

Comment: As a side note, I strongly recommend this guide that talks about the many wonderful things flexbox can do for you, including reversing order of elements: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/