# How do I change the direction of every other "row" in a wrapped row flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for a way to display an ordered list of components in an "S" pattern (where you can trace the start to the end of the list without lifting up your pen, for example).

This is what the end goal looks like:
[image]

For the life of me, I can't come up with a way to do this. If it was a column with a set number of rows, I could do something like `:nth-child(even) { flex-direction: row-reverse; }` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803871/changing-rows-order-every-other-one) post suggests.

Here is the basic markup:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  place-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1 1 320px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  /* Adjust the width as needed */
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}


/* This doesn't work */

.flex-container:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">6</div>
  <div class="flex-item">7</div>
  <div class="flex-item">8</div>
  <div class="flex-item">9</div>
  <!-- this list is dynamic! -->
</div>
```

[Here is a jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cn2k7rdw/7/) with the basic setup I have in a production application. One thing to keep in mind is this is coming from a 3rd party application (Inductive Automation's Ignition Perspective), so I pretty much need to do things this way, as I'll have a dynamic number of components in the list.

Comment: Your picture shows two elements to a row, your CSS hints at three, what exactly are the constraints on width?

Comment: The components have  a set width, but the container where the components reside is responsive, so it could have 2, 3 or X number of components. The number of components and screen width are both dynamic

Comment: I think you’ll need to calculate the number of items in a row outside of CSS, eg with JS. After that CSS would do.

Answer (score 1):

Doable using CSS grid if you know the number of columns. I have a (long) article detailing such techniques that worth reading in case you need more complex configuration: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/#grid-patterns

For 2 columns

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <!-- this list is dynamic! -->
</div>
```

And for 3 columns:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item:nth-child(6n + 6) {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.item:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.item:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <!-- this list is dynamic! -->
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to assume each row is to have two columns.

Comment: @AHaworth or 3 columns which I assume it's the case considering the flex-basis he's using

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question with, apparently, no good answers yet. It's probably not possible to achieve a snake-like flow with CSS alone, without some constraints (such as a fixed number of items).

In any case, here are some references—too many to list in the comments, but also not clear duplicates. Perhaps they will provide useful guidance.

- [grid-auto-flow in snake lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58598575/3597276)
- [Flexbox: Alternate "row" and "row-reverse" according to row's number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47091822/3597276)
- [Is there a way to snake/queue the flow of items in a CSS Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56450887/3597276)
- [Snake-like alignment in css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41064753/3597276)
- [CSS multi-column snake pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58829866/3597276)

Comment: actually it's possible in this particular case where the number of column is known

Comment: This isn't really much of an answer, and it reads like a list of dupes that it should've been closed in favor of, however the excellent Temani Afif provided a working example in his answer, so it appears to also be possible

Comment: @j08691, "possible" with constraints, as I mentioned in my answer. When we know the number of items or columns, a solution can be had with relative ease. But without those constraints, there's really no solution with CSS. (I didn't assume a 2-column layout from the OP based solely on the image.)

Comment: In terms of duplicates, I didn't see a clear connection between this question and any of the posts listed in my answer.